# Migration to non-muslim land because of social persecution because of racism

Tags: fiqh, non-muslim-countries

Is it allowed for Muslims to migrate to a non-Muslim land if he is persecuted socially for racial reasons?

I read it somewhere that Muslims can migrate to a non-Muslim land if they are persecuted without crime, imprisoned or property confiscated?

I am asking for my ownself. I am not imprisoned or my property confiscated but I suffer from social persecution due to racism.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “non-Muslim” lands. You see, this is the problem. Too many people view the world through this lens, as if there really is an “us” and a “them”. In reality those lines are not so clear. In fact they don’t exist at all.

Comment: How can a land be called a "muslim" land if they practice racism?  This is against the teachings of Muhammed pbuh and Islam.

Answer (score 0):

Migration to another non-Muslim land is possible whenever it should be a choice, when there was a powerful Islamic empire from the last decades, people was immigrating to another non-Muslim lands for the purpose of trading, however this was the main reason for non-Muslims in that land to accept Islam as a religion due to Muslim traders behavior and honesty. A big example of this is the Indian subcontinent which has a relatively large number of Muslims. In sharia we now that hadith of prophet Mohamed -Peace upon him- that said that Allah supports the honesty state by victory even it was infidel and he doesn't supports the non-honesty one even it was a believer. Also in Qurán Allah said for those who feels weakened in their societies that his land -and all of things is for Allah- is wide enough to immigrate and worship for Allah in such a way that you feel satisfied.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Answers here should be elaborate, and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour](//islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](//islam.stackexchange.com/help), and refer to [how to answer questions](//islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can immigrate in a non-Muslim land and you can go with any reason you have. See, prophet Muhammad did once and he immigrated in a land where is a bunch of disbelievers and then he died in his own land where it was bunch of disbelievers, where he born. So in other wards you can immigrate anywhere you wish either for vacation, either for better life but this depends also if you are able to perform your prayers, if you are able to perform prayers then, yes, you can. But if: not, then you can stay there but to move in a Muslim land to perform it.